# what event is used in order to show an alert message on selecting a value in the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am using autocomplete api of jquery in order to fetch the name from the database.But i want to show an alert message on selecting a name from the textbox displayed.I will show an image for better understanding.

[image]

When i type "S" it will display all the records containing "S". So the question is if i select Eg:-"Sparsh Hospital" then the webpage should display an alert message containing "Sparsh Hospital".I tried many event handlers but none of them are working.So if any event handler then suggest me please.My code is as below

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>   

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         var selectedValue = ''; 
        $("#country").autocomplete("list.jsp")
         $('#country').change(function() {
                selectedValue = $(this).val(); // store value in variable
               alert(selectedValue = $(this).val());
                });
                });
   </script>

</head>
<body>
<br><br><center>
<font face="verdana" size="2">

<br><br><br><br>

    Select Country   :  
    <input type="text" id="country" name="country" class="input_text"/>

</font>
</body>
</html>
```

list.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>

 <% 
    try{      
         String s[]=null;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_database","root","root");
        Statement st=con.createStatement(); 
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select Company_Name from marketing_database.lead");

            List li = new ArrayList();

            while(rs.next()) 
            {               
                li.add(rs.getString(1));
            }  

            String[] str = new String[li.size()];           
            Iterator it = li.iterator();

            int i = 0;
            while(it.hasNext())
            {
                String p = (String)it.next();   
                str[i] = p;
                i++;
            }

            //jQuery related start      
                String query = (String)request.getParameter("q");

                int cnt=1;
                for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++)
                {
                    if(str[j].toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
                    {
                        out.print(str[j]+"\n");
                        if(cnt>=5)
                            break;
                        cnt++;
                    }
                }
            //jQuery related end    


        rs.close(); 
        st.close(); 
        con.close();

            } 
        catch(Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

 %>
```

Comment: It would probably be best if you use the autocomplete plugin's event hooks if there are any. Can you give us a working fiddle if possible.

Comment: @KiiroSora09 I cant provide working because mysql database is associated with the code

Answer (score 3):

If you're using devbridge's [Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete):

Use a settings object to set the instance up, with your URL and an event handler on selecting a value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectedValue = '';
  $( '#country' ).autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: 'list.jsp',
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
      selectedValue = suggestion.value;
      alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
  });
});
```

---

If you're using jQuery UI's [Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/):

Handle the `autocompleteselect` event rather than the `change` event and access the value of the selected item by using `ui.item.value` rather than `.val()`, where `ui` is the second argument provided in the event handler function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var selectedValue = '';
   $( '#country' ).autocomplete({
       source: 'list.jsp',
       select: function(e, ui) {
         selectedValue = ui.item.value;
         alert(selectedValue);
       }
   });
 });
```

See https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: @chittioneterahertz What library are you using? Can you link the page?

Comment: I dont know about the link but i downloaded the libraries and placed in a folder(that i created in an eclipse project) and using it.The libraries are "jquery-1.4.2.min.js" and "jquery.autocomplete.js"

Comment: @chittioneterahertz I can see that from your code, but `jquery.autocomplete.js` could be a lot of different libraries, esp. if you renamed it. Could it be this? https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Comment: Both methods are not working for me.I used the code from this website http://www.java4s.com/jquery-tutorials/example-get-autocomplete-feature-in-javajsp-with-jquery-api/

Comment: That plugin is very old and has been superseded by jQuery UI's Autocomplete. You should use jQuery UI's latest version and then the code I provided.

Comment: Can you provide the link for the autocomplete latest plugins??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110251/discussion-between-chitti-oneterahertz-and-lerouche).